# this.state.xxx.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display data from the state, but when I try to map data, there's an error saying

> this.state.xxx.map is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Content extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            gifs: [{}]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=nNwaquW24K8gLDmrxGTmawppQoTkXxLQ&tag=&rating=G')
        .then( response => {
            this.setState({ gifs: response.data.data})
        })
        .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);  
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.gifs.map( gif =>
                    <p>{gif.url}</p>
                    )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: this is errors message that I get]

Comment: Print out `response.data.data` and make sure it's an array.

Comment: The API just returns an object not array. Change the API endpoint which gives you an array of gifs.

Answer (score 0):

`response.data.data` is an object and `map` is not an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) function.

`this.setState({ gifs: response.data.data})` replaces `gifs` with the incoming object instead of adding it to the array. You can add `response.data.data` to the state like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=nNwaquW24K8gLDmrxGTmawppQoTkXxLQ&tag=&rating=G')
    .then( response => {
        this.setState({ gifs: [...this.state.gifs, response.data.data] }); // This line is different
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);  
    })
}
```

Comment: how I can do that? I'm completely beginner to this stuff

Comment: edited my answer to show you where the change should be made

Answer (score 0):

The `response.data,data` from `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=nNwaquW24K8gLDmrxGTmawppQoTkXxLQ&tag=&rating=G` is an object. You cannot map an object.

Or if you want to add the object to `this.state.gifs`, you need try this code below:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  gifs: [...prevState.gifs, response.data.data]
}));
```

Comment: Thank it works, but how I can show all data in an object? it is possible to convert an object to array? so I can map it

Answer (score 0):

Here is working demo :

the api will response of single gif image and it is object , 
in your state gifs is array , so you have to either push new object into gifs array or you can use spread operator '...' `[...this.state.gifs,newGIFobject]` to add in gif array .

```js
const {Component} = React;

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            gifs:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=nNwaquW24K8gLDmrxGTmawppQoTkXxLQ&tag=&rating=G')
        .then( response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({ gifs: [...this.state.gifs, response.data.data]})
        })
        .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);  
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.gifs.map(gif => <p>{gif.url}</p>)}
                    
            </div>
        );
    }
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Content />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```